# how to setting docker container (wordpress) only using domain to visit?

Tags: wordpress, docker, caddy

I build a wordpress blog by docker.Using the 8080 port.But i want to only using my domain to visit the blog ,the ip and the other domain can't .

I try to use caddy proxy the 8080 port to my domain , but it did not work.

So i try to edit the apache.conf , but when i exec into the container,i found there didn't has vi ,so i can't edit anything.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:5.7
docker run --name some-wordpress --link some-mysql:mysql -p 8080:80 -d wordpress
```

I just want to know how i can set only using domain to visit my blog .
Could some one tell me ?

Comment: if you are using ubuntu image run `apt install vim` to install vim editor.

Comment: @KishoreKadiyala the container is using the debian, so i try `apt install vim` already , it doesn't work.

Comment: did you run `apt udpate` before? what do you mean by doesn't work? are you getting an error?